# Android Progress bar set level

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to change the progress bar color based on different levels.

Drawable used by the progress bar

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal_green"/>
    <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal_red"/>

</layer-list>
```

I am loading the progress bar like so:

```
// viewHolder.budgetProgress is a ProgressBar 
viewHolder.budgetProgress.setMax(100);
// No matter what level I change, the drawable used is always the lowest one.
viewHolder.budgetProgress.getProgressDrawable().setLevel(0);
viewHolder.budgetProgress.setProgress(95);
```

The problem is that the drawable used is always the lowest one, so in this case red. If I swap the `progress_horizontal_red` and `progress_horizontal_green` around, then the progress bar is always green.

Comment: you should specify all levels in the layer-list

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tutorial : [Progress bar implementation using Level list drawable](http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com.tr/2010/10/progress-bar-implementation-using-level.html)